# CSS - Multiple border types in one line

Tags: css

Quick question, it might be stupid or easy. I don't know. That is why I'm asking.

Is it possible to call multiple border properties in one CSS line?

For example:

```
border-top, border-right: xxx;
```

Or even:

```
border-top,right,left: xxx;
```

I was curious about this.

Thanks

Comment: No, Each of those is a separate property. It depends on what you are trying to do though, there are options.

Comment: Why would I get a downvote for my question?

Comment: I have no idea, it's not mine...but "lack of research" is one possibility.

Comment: Yes I guess that is it.

Answer (score 3):

It will be something like this:

```css
.border {
  border-width: 1px 2px 3px 0;
  border-style: solid dotted dashed none;
  border-color: red blue green transparent;

  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">Mixed borders</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just like `margin`, `padding` etc, you can give 4 values (top,right,bottom,left) *or* 2 values (top&bottom, left&right)

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
#a {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#b {
  border-color: green;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 3px 9px 0;
}
#c {
  border-color: tomato;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<br />
<div id="b"></div>
<br />
<div id="c"></div>
```